# Triggering auto gen code Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, auto-generate, android-jetpack-navigation

I am learning *Kotlin*, and trying to set up *Navigation* in my app.

I am unable to find/trigger the auto generated code in *Android Studio*.  Based on the navigation tutorial, I need to reference it to trigger an action on demand. It's my understanding *HomeFragmentDirections* is an auto-gen class.

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_button)?.setOnClickListener {
    val flowStepNumberArg = 1
    val action = HomeFragmentDirections.nextAction(flowStepNumberArg)
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

I have been following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation directions get auto-generated only after a successful build. You should either go to `Build` -> `Make Project`

or click on [image].